# Android SQLite3 query using WHERE clause doesn't return results even though the data exists

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I am developing an Android application with an `SQLite3` database holding some of the data for offline access. I am trying to query the database using `rawQuery`, and a `WHERE` clause querying for a String. However, it's not returning any results, and neither is SQLite3 on the command line using the same Query, however a copy of the database in MySQL format executes the query just fine and gets the correct results.

Here is my code:

```
String query = "SELECT id FROM plaques WHERE subject = ?";
String subjectName = "Florence Nightingale";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{subjectName});
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do {
        try {
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

(the database is being selected, using the `Context` and this is working).

So the query (`SELECT id FROM plaques WHERE subject='Florence Nightingale'` works perfectly in MySQL on an exact copy of the database/table, but not in SQLite3. `cursor.movetoFirst()` is returned as `false`, indicating no results are returned). Does SQLite3 encode the text in a different way or something? If I try to a query where the `WHERE` clause selects a int value, the query works fine and returns the expected results.

Comment: Did all other queries work as sometimes create table query dont executes because of any error ?

Comment: @JagjitSingh all queries involving numerical values (ints, doubles, etc) work but String values don't

Comment: 1) Did you try to dummy up the query and change to where id=? instead of String just to make sure it is String look up issue? 2) Do you have any records in the table with subject='Florence...'?

Comment: Are you sure that the data is in your database? You can try and pull a copy of it and use sqlitebrowser to explore your tables and verify that the query is working there.

Comment: @Nambari yes, I edited the question to include this - all numerical values in the `WHERE` clause work, but Strings don't. I definitely have values with Florence Nightingale in the `subject` column.

Comment: How did you confirm that you have subject with 'Florence...'?

Comment: @DanailAlexiev yes the data is there, I ran the query in SQLite command line, which returned false and manually verified the data exists.

Comment: How do you know that you have the data in the column, when the database says you have not? What is the output of `SELECT subject FROM plaques WHERE id = whatever`?

Comment: @Tom Oakley  try like this and then see results SELECT id FROM plaques WHERE subject ='"+ subjectName+"'";

Comment: @Nambari @ClL. I opened the database in SQLite command line and verified the data exists using `SELECT * FROM plaques;`. It just won't work within a `WHERE` clause (either within Android Studio or in the command line).

Comment: @JagjitSingh thanks for the suggestion, I've tried that and it still won't return anything, either within Android Studio or on SQLite command line.

Comment: you might try the sqlite function `trim()`. there must be some hard-to-see whitespace somewhere

Comment: @CL. tried your suggestion, it returns the expected result ("Florence Nightingale").

Comment: @DavidM thanks for the suggestion, I will give this a go a bit later (got some other business to complete first, sorry).

Comment: Oookay, what is the output of `SELECT hex(subject) FROM plaques WHERE id = whatever`?

Comment: @Tom Oakley did u get db as db=this.getWritableDatabase(); and please post whole code for better solutions

Comment: @TomOakley I've had trouble before with DB columns of type NONE (which is supported by sqlite). When using the android wrapper's parametrised query functionality all I got was empty results. Is it possible that you forgot to explicitly set the data type of the `subject` column?

Comment: @JagjitSingh I have got the DB using `SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();` - this has worked on other queries where the `WHERE` clause is testing numerical values so it definitely works.

Comment: @DanailAlexiev the text fields have a data type of `text`, I'll research the other possibilities for this field.

Comment: @CL. the result of the query you gave me was null too :(

Comment: It cannot return anything less just with the `hex()` added.